# Loud buzzing noise using Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 on Macbook

Tags: audio-recording, recording, audio-interfaces, feedback, problem

I just bought a used Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 from Guitar Center online. The focusrite website says that no drivers are needed for the mac, and don't even have any links for downloads. I have a '15 Macbook Pro running Yosemite and using Garageband. I have the interface selected for the audio input/output. I get a really loud buzzing noise no matter what I do. Doesn't matter if I have an XLR or 1/4" cable in or out, or any of the knobs turned one way or the other. There's always a persistent loud buzzing. I can hear myself very very faintly through the buzzing, but the noise is totally overpowering. I've tried everything I've seen around in other forums. Contacted focusrite, but who knows when they'll get back to me. I need help!

Comment: do you have another cable? , Generally start changing ports and cables to troubleshoot, if the problem persists cut it down, disconnect the monitors and make a recording, see if the buzz is from the preamp section which is the most logical thing. Use a balanced XLR cable , i had problems with a focusrite card when i used non balanced cables!

Comment: I've had good success with Focusrite support, once I waited on hold long enough.